# How map my custom data type with AWS Athena data type?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am uploading the below JSON format data into the AWS S3 bucket.

```
{
  "time": 1663090620000,
  "data": [
    [
      1,
      [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

I have data types in my object for the fields in the JSON as mentioned below.

```
time - Long
data - List<List<Object>>
```

I tried creating the below schema in Athena with partition projection by pointing to S3 bucket but I am not able to map the **data** field in my JSON data with amazon Athena supported data types - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/data-types.html.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test_data_db`.`test_data_table`(
  `time` bigint COMMENT 'from deserializer', 
  `data` array<array<double>> COMMENT 'from deserializer')
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `id` string, 
  `creation_date` date
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://test-data-bucket/test-data'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'projection.creation_date.format'='yyyy-MM-dd', 
  'projection.creation_date.range'='2010-01-01,2050-12-31', 
  'projection.creation_date.type'='date', 
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.id.type'='injected', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://test-data-bucket/test-data/id=${id}/creation_date=${creation_date}', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1663357524')
```

Could you please help me how to map my JSON **data** field with the Athena data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through your table definition and sample data provided and understood the problem. The actual data has three levels of nested array items where as your table definition has only two levels defined.

So I tried changing *`data array<array<double>>`* to
*`data array<array<array<double>>>`* and was able to query the data field fine. It is up to you to decide on the data type as `double` or `int` as per your use case.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My data is like this - [[1,[0,0,0]]]

Comment: yes it depends on what datatype you chose. In your question it was mentioned as double and the output in comment comes out when it is integer. @shivakumarsajjan does this answer helped you?

Comment: The array of array will have multiple data types, it should support both mentioned below structure.
array<array<float>> or array<array<array<double>>>. So I want to generic type like array<array<object>

Comment: I don't understand the comment, you are still not able to query table with the schema provided in answer?

Comment: sorry for that I have edited my comment above

Comment: I still don't understand how it is related to the answer I wrote. have you tried using the schema and let me know what errors you see?

Comment: I tried but do not remember the errors. I will try it again and let you know the errors. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I am getting this error after adding you mentioned data structure. 
```HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: java.io.IOException: Start of Array expected
This query ran against the "test_data" database, unless qualified by the query. Please post the error message on our forum  or contact customer support```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248205/discussion-between-prabhakar-reddy-and-shivakumar-sajjan).

Comment: It worked after your suggestion by changing ROW FORMAT SERDE - org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe. Thank you